# Flutter: How to access context from static method?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using Flutter [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) package and every one of its methods requires the callback to be a static function.
How can I access a context in the callback to show an alert dialog or add an event to the stream when the callback is triggered?

```
 static void callback() {
    // context ?
  }

 void scheduleAlarm() async {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(duration, id, callback);
  }
```

Comment: `static void callback(Context context) `

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I am getting the same situation.